# How do I add the £ sign with code linked to phpmyadmin?

Tags: php

I can't seem to add a £ sign to the price of my products without an error.

```
echo '<td><center>' . $row->ProductPrice.'</td></center>';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You need to show us your attempts and what error you're getting. There's nothing strange about the posted code.

Comment: Also, PHPMyAdmin is a web based management application for managing MySQL-databases. Your code doesn't have anything to do with PHPMyAdmin unless you're modifying the code in that application.

Comment: Is this about the half-way centered table cell, or a syntax woe?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing strings with variables. When a string is specified in double quotes, variables are parsed within it. You should use curly braces to differentiate strings with variable references.

Your could be simplified like so:

```
echo "<td><center>£{$row->ProductPrice}</td></center>";
```

Have read of the documentation for strings, it will give you more control of your code writing: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Before we know what the OP actually have tried and what the error is, we have no idea what the real issue is. There's nothing wrong with the way the OP is  concatenate the string. It's more about personal preference when it comes to concatenation vs variable interpolation.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was responding to what the OP had written prior to the edit they made to make it clearer.